# How to change the Direction of Action Buttons of Window Manager (Explorer) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I need to change the direction of Action Buttons (Close,Maximize and Minimize)of Window Manager (Explorer) in Windows 7 **from Right side of window to Left of Window** Just like in Ubuntu.

Because mostly I use Ubuntu so it became my habit that if I have to close or minimize the window my hand automatically goes to left side of screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third-party utility for this named [LeftSider](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/LeftSider.shtml).

The application runs in the System Tray and moves all Title bar buttons to the left side. Closing the application restores the buttons to right.

I don't think that it will work flawlessly, it might break badly in some applications.

[Source](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/move-windows-close-minimize-buttons-to-left-side-like-mac-os-x/)